# Mysql container password security

Tags: mysql, docker, security, passwords, docker-container

I have a couple of questions on password security in mysql container. I use [mysql/mysql-server:8.0 image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql-server/mysql/mysql-server/8.0/images/sha256-bcb56714933157b2bb203408b6b5e292559d8b8a42d4e3acb8514ae783225e13?context=explore).

The 1st question is

Is using MYSQL_PASSWORD env var in mysql container based on the image above secure?
I elaborate a bit more about this below.

I set mysql password for mysql container by k8s env var injection, that is, setting MYSQL_PASSWORD env var in mysql container by using k8s secrets via env var in k8s manifest file. Is this secure? That is my 1st question. [Notes following table in this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html) say using MYSQL_PWD(note this is not MYSQL_PASSWORD) env var is extremely insecure because ps cmd can display the environment of running processes and any other user can exploit it. Does this also apply to container situation using MYSQL_PASSWORD instead of MYSQL_PWD?

The 2nd question is

Is running `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -p${MYSQL_PASSWORD}` in the same mysql container secure?

I need to run similar cmd in k8s readiness probe. [The warning section of this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html) says running `mysql -phard-coded-password` is not secure. I'm not sure if the password is still not secure even if the env var is used like above and I'm also not sure if this warning applies to container case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your security concerns include protecting your database against an attacker with legitimate login access to the host, then the most secure option is to pass the database credentials in a file.  Both command-line options and environment variables, in principle, are visible via `ps`.

For the case of the database container, the standard Docker Hub images don't have paths to provide credentials this way.  If you create the initial database elsewhere and then mount the resulting data directory on your production system (consider this like restoring a backup) then you won't need to set any of the initial data variables.

```sh
here$ docker run -it -v "$PWD/mysql:/var/lib/mysql" -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=... mysql
^C
here$ scp -r ./mysql there:
here$ ssh there
# without any -e MYSQL_*=... options
there$ docker run -v "$PWD/mysql:/var/lib/mysql" -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

More broadly, there are two other things I'd take into account here:

1. Anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can very easily root the entire host.  So if you're broadly granting Docker socket access to anyone with login permission, they can easily find out the credentials (if nothing else they can `docker exec` a `cat` command in the container to dump the credentials file).
2. Any `ENV` directives in a Dockerfile will be visible in `docker history` and `docker inspect` output to anyone who gets a copy of the image.  Never put any sort of credentials in your Dockerfile!

Practically, I'd suggest that, if you're this concerned about your database credentials, you're probably dealing with some sort of production system; and if you're dealing with a production system, the set of people who can log into it is limited and trusted.  In that case an environment variable setting isn't exposing credentials to anyone who couldn't read it anyways.

(In the more specific case of a Kubernetes Pod with environment variables injected by a Secret, in most cases almost nobody will have login access to an individual Node and the Secret can be protected by Kubernetes RBAC.  This is pretty safe from prying eyes if set up correctly.)